# How actionssdk cloud functions is working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

index.js file

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin     = require('firebase-admin');
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = actionssdk({debug: true});
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', function (conv, input) {
    conv.ask('<speak>Hi! <break time="1"/> ' +
        'You are entering into samplejs5 application by typing ' +
        ("<say-as >" + input + "</say-as>.</speak>"));
});

const getUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log("req.params.uid--------->",req.params.uid)
    const uid = req.params.uid;
    /*const doc = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${uid}`)
    doc.get().then(snapshot => {
        res.send(snapshot.data())
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    })*/
})

 exports.dairyProduct = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Action.json

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "testapp"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "Talk to Dairy Product"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "testapp": {
      "name": "testapp",
      "url": "https://us-central1-samplejs6-id.cloudfunctions.net/dairyProduct",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2,
      "inDialogIntents": [
        {
          "name": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "locale": "en"
}
```

I am new to actionsdk, I want to get userUID, Since i am using dairyProduct function, how to call getUser? what would be the value of UID, 
Please share the guide for creating user, and end user authentication with sample, how they are calling the functions

For calling main intent, we have to type talk to test app, Once main Intent is called, how to authenticate the user